# Call procedure with nested table as parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

How code procedure with nested table parameter? In table test I need insert data from loop eg.  1,2,3...

plsql

```
Declare
      TYPE code_nt is table of varchar2(10);
      l_codes code_nt := code_nt();
    begin    ​
    
      ​FOR i IN 1..APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01.COUNT LOOP  
        l_codes.extend;
        l_codes(i) := to_char(i);
      ​END LOOP;
      
      //here call procedure
      //PKG_EMP.INSERT_EMP(PAR_1); 
end;
```

package:

```
create or replace PACKAGE PKG_EMP AS
    
    TYPE code_nt is table of varchar2(10);
    l_codes code_nt := code_nt();
    
    procedure INSERT_EMP (PAR_1  code_nt);
END;
    
    
create or replace PACKAGE BODY PKG_EMP AS
      
    procedure INSERT_EMP (PAR_1  code_nt) AS
    BEGIN
         INSERT INTO test (ID) VALUES (value from code_nt);
    END;  
end;
```

Comment: @MT0 gave you the answer.  Note that there is likely no point in declaring the package variable `l_codes` in your package.  Just declare the type there and declare variables of the type where they are needed.

Comment: @JustinCave Can you describe this in answer. Tnx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will not work as `code_nt` is a locally defined type in both your PL/SQL function and the PL/SQL anonymous block and despite having the same name and signature they are different data types.

You need to use the same data type in both:

```sql
Declare
  l_codes PKG_EMP.code_nt := PKG_EMP.code_nt();
begin    ​
  FOR i IN 1..APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01.COUNT LOOP  
    l_codes.extend;
    l_codes(i) := to_char(i);
    -- or
    -- l_codes(i) := TO_CHAR( APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01(i) );
  ​END LOOP;
      
  PKG_EMP.INSERT_EMP(l_codes); 
END;
/
```

You can declare your package as:

```sql
CREATE PACKAGE PKG_EMP AS
  TYPE code_nt is table of varchar2(10);

  PROCEDURE INSERT_EMP (PAR_1 code_nt);
END;
/

CREATE PACKAGE BODY PKG_EMP AS
  procedure INSERT_EMP (PAR_1 code_nt) AS
  BEGIN
    FORALL i IN 1 .. par_1.COUNT
      INSERT INTO test (ID) VALUES ( par_1(i) );
  END;  
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0a6fa52834de7d3042278c685e9074ff)*